# how to configure marvel on found

Tags: elasticsearch-marvel, elastic-found

i want to use marvel on found cluster. i have referred to these links https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/configuration.html , https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/marvel.html to use it on local. but how to configure it on elastic found ?? marvel agents has to be installed on each cluster to be functional. but how do i do that.

below are the plugins that i have selected in found configuration

[image]

there is no option to select marvel in the plugins. marvel dashboard and application can be installed in kibana, but it won't work without the marvel agent.

is it preinstalled by default in found?? if so how do i configure it ??